# is it possible to insert data into a separate page using itextsharp through a loop

Tags: asp.net-core, itext

I have a template file. then I take the data from the database and fill in the template. I now need to take data through a loop and paste it into other pages.

```
var reader = new PdfReader(templateFilePath);
var fontPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "fonts", "microsoft_sans_serif.ttf");

var ms = new MemoryStream();
var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

byte[] bytes;

using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
{
    var canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
    var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    //var font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

    canvas.BeginText();
    canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 40);

    //this data will be in the array and insert each object of the array into a separate page

    {canvas.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER,
        $"{student.StudentUser.FirstName} {student.StudentUser.LastName}",
        (pageSize.Left + pageSize.Right) / 2, pageSize.GetTop(Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(95)), 0);

    canvas.EndText();

    stamper.Close();
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

var fileName =
    $"{student.StudentUser.FirstName.ToLower()}_{student.StudentUser.LastName.ToLower()}_{student.Year.OnlineTestStartDate.Year}_certificate.pdf";

return File(bytes, "application/pdf", fileName);
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, `stamper.GetOverContent` will work for other pages.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, this method takes the first page from an existing file. and I need to use this page as a template for subsequent pages.

Comment: *"if I am not mistaken, this method takes the first page"* - only if you use `1` as argument. For `2` it takes the second one. Etc etc

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have poorly explained my problem. I have a template file and with the GetOverContent method I get the first page as a template. Next there is an array with the data of users. And here I need to create a new page for each user using the previously taken template using the method GetOverContent

Comment: if I use 2 as a parameter, it will not receive 2 pages since it does not exist

Comment: Bad questions beget bad answers. Create a new document, (1) import the page to the content, add your text, create a new page, repeat from (1).

Comment: @Саламат *"seem to have poorly explained my problem..."* - that means that the `PdfStamper` is not the right iText class for you to use as it is explicitly for manipulating the existing pages of a PDF. As Paulo proposes, start a `Document`/`PdfWriter`, import the template page, iterate over your datasets, in the loop add a new page, add the template to it, and add the data to the `DirectContent`.

Comment: Thanks mkl. I tried as you said. It remains only to import the template

Comment: _var canvas = writer.DirectContent;
canvas.CreateTemplate(page.Width, page.Height);_

@mkl I cannot create a template from another pdf file. in this section of code I can only set the page size, but I need all the pictures and text that are.

Comment: thanks to all! especially @MKL for a detailed explanation